# how to work on with email alias in odoo 8?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

Anybody please help me with Odoo mailing aliases for a corporate domain. I have been behind this two to three days and failing to get the work done. I am pretty much confused between the email to be set in user preferences and email aliases and whether the outgoing mail server id should be set in the preferences email ?

Answer (score 0):

Just you should follow the below blog to understand the email alias and domain setting for OpenERP.

https://opensourceenterprise.wordpress.com/2013/08/16/activate-enterprise-social-communication-in-openerp-production-server/

we have to do the same setting for Odoo 8.0 and check it.

I hope my answer may helpful for you :)

Comment: Thanks a lot , but i already had visited that link and was not able to do it according to my needs :)